# CSS to control thumbnail image size within DIV

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm setting up a Wordpress image gallery using the Avada theme and and I'd like to be able to increase the size of the gallery thumbnail images (e.g., 200% or 300%) and center them vertically within the .fusion-gallery-image div.

You can see the problem withe the brochure thumbnail in this image:

[image]

Here's the fusion-gallery-image div and related elements for the brochure div.

```html
<div class="fusion-gallery-image"><a href="http://bigidearesults.com/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2.jpg" class="fusion-lightbox" data-rel="iLightbox[728c57306ad178f5910]" data-title="brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2" title="brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2" data-caption=""><img src="http://bigidearesults.com/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2-400x201.jpg" alt="" title="brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2" aria-label="brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2" class="img-responsive wp-image-11546" srcset="http://bigidearesults.com/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2-200x100.jpg 200w, http://bigidearesults.com/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2-400x201.jpg 400w, http://bigidearesults.com/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2-600x301.jpg 600w, http://bigidearesults.com/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2-800x401.jpg 800w, http://bigidearesults.com/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2-1200x602.jpg 1200w, http://bigidearesults.com/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/brochure-saguaro-ranch-brochure-2.jpg 1597w" sizes="(min-width: 2200px) 100vw, (min-width: 824px) 363px, (min-width: 732px) 545px, (min-width: 640px) 732px, "></a></div>
```

Please let me know how to increase the size of these gallery images and center them vertically within the the fusion-gallery-image div.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please do not add external links to your website. Include the minimal code to reproduce the issue. This question will become useless to future visitors once you update your link or code. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The visual helps, maybe an image instead of the link

Comment: You made a good point. External links removed and image added.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would have an image that is big enough/fits the general size of the div so you don't have to mess with increasing the size and rather it's just about fitting it.

For example that book image is a good 100% width but too short vertically. Once you have that use flexbox to center vertically and horizontally.

```
.fusion-gallery-image {    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```